# How do I change file name that contains a date automatically in python

Tags: python

I am trying to copy data from one excel file to another automatically using python, currently i have to manually update the date in the excel file name every morning. Is there a way to automatically update the date in the excel file name. I am very new to any form of programming, trying to learn to keep my job.

I have tried to use the time date function and declare this as a variable and copy this into code but no luck

```
import datetime

Filedate= (datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1))

exceldate= Filedate.strftime("%Y",)+Filedate.strftime("%m",)+Filedate.strftime("%d",)


import pyexcel as p

p.save_book_as(file_name="Q:\Valuations\Currency Options\YieldX Daily Statsexceldate.xls",#CHANGE DATE #manual entry. 
               dest_file_name='YieldX Daily Stats20190522.xlsx')#CHANGE DATE manual entry
```

Comment: You need to update only one file name or multiple? The program should by working in background?

Comment: Multiple. Yes it does work in the background I just click run using Jupyter and it runs files I only pasted the part of the code I am struggling with. Many thanks for the quick response

Comment: what is the date format in files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are trying to do is, open a excel file everyday, and rename its filename to current date, where the previous excel file will have the date of yesterday.

```
import datetime
import pyexcel as p

yesterday = (datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")

today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

p.save_book_as(file_name="Q:\Valuations\Currency Options\YieldX Daily Stats" + yesterday + ".xls",
               dest_file_name='YieldX Daily Stats' + today + '.xlsx')
```

The above code, when executed will change the name of the `.xls` file which was created yesterday (with its Timestamp), to the current date.

**Example:-**

If a file named `YieldX Daily Stats20190530.xls` existed yesterday, today its name will be modified to `YieldX Daily Stats20190531.xls`

Comment: Thank you thank you, this code is applicable on some many other areas,

Answer (score 3):

My approach is to split filename into part that contains date and the rest, then replace date with current one.

```
import os
import datetime
import re

# get xls files
xls_files = [file for file in os.listdir(os.getcwd()) if file.endswith('.xls')]

# get current date
now = datetime.datetime.now()

# change names
for item in xls_files:
    # split name and date part
    name_parts = item.split('.')
    get_date = re.findall('\d+-\d+-\d+', name_parts[0])
    name_string_part = name_parts[0].replace(get_date[0], '')
    # create new name
    new_name = name_string_part + str(now.day) + '-' + str(now.month) + '-' + str(now.year) + '_' + '.xls'
    # rename file
    os.rename(item, new_name)
```

Comment: Your code is also good may use it in another way. Thanks for the response I have being struggling for weeks with the issue